# Make map faster in vim

Tags: vim

I want to create these two mappings in my vimrc file:

```
map [ {
map ] }
```

but the problem is, there are a lot of mappings that start with [ or ] and their presence makes my maps slow, because right after pressing [ or ] it needs to wait a second to make sure no other characters are coming. any way to get rid of all maps that start with [ or ]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those mappings probably come from the unimpaired plugin, which defines a lot of them. You can check with `:verbose map [`.

You either have to reconfigure the plugin to use a different prefix, or get rid of the plugin. You can also `:unmap [o`, `:unmap [e`, etc. the mappings individually; unfortunately, there's no wildcard `:unmap`.

I would still ask you to reconsider; there are also many built-in commands (`:help [`) that, even though they don't contribute to your mapping's delay, would be completely unavailable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique besides disabling other plugins is to modify the mapping to be slightly different. 
e.g.

```
map [[ {
```

Where pressing it twice equals the desired mapping. Or:

```
map <leader>[ {
```

As Ingo mentioned, the `[` character has many other uses.